# WPF DataGrid ItemsSource Issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid, itemssource

Please let it be known that I am relatively new to WPF. I am creating a new `ObservableCollection` with the type of my simple data class, and assigning that to the `ItemsSource` property of my `DataGrid`. Before I go into my problem here is the code:

**XAML**:

```
<my:DataGrid SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell" Height="113" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,22,0,0" Name="addressGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" Background="#FFE2E2E2" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFA4CFF2" BorderBrush="#FF7C7C7C" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="White" PreviewKeyDown="addressGrid_PreviewKeyDown" CellEditEnding="addressGrid_CellEditEnding" BeginningEdit="addressGrid_BeginningEdit" PreparingCellForEdit="addressGrid_PreparingCellForEdit">
        <my:DataGrid.Columns>
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding Path=Value}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
        <my:DataGridTextColumn Header="Index" Visibility="Hidden" Binding="{Binding Path=Index}"></my:DataGridTextColumn>
        </my:DataGrid.Columns>
</my:DataGrid>
```

**Data Class**:

```
public class PropertyFields
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

**Population**:

```
ObservableCollection<PropertyFields> propertyList = new ObservableCollection<PropertyFields>();
for (int i = 0; i < m_pFields.FieldCount - 1; ++i)
{
   propertyList.Add(new PropertyFields() {Name = m_pFields.Field[i].AliasName, Value = DisplayedValueForRow(i), Index = i});
}

// Set ItemSource to populate grid
addressGrid.ItemsSource = propertyList;
```

---

***More information about the population method:***

I am building this solution with ArcGIS framework, so some things are not "System" in ways.

- `m_pFields` is an `IFields` interface object that allows me to store spatial layer information
- `IFields` has a `FieldCount` property which returns a number of fields in the collection
- `DisplayedValueForRow(i)` calls another ArcGIS obj method `IPropertySet.GetProperty()`  and returns the value.

---

***The Problem:***

Everything is being populated as it should be, but for some odd reason it is re-creating the three columns (Name, Value, Index) again *ON TOP* of populating the ones created in XAML -- In turn ending up with 2 sets of the same data. I found this to be weird behavior, as I swear I have seen people bind to their grid this way before.

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit

Thanks to ChrisO's comment, I found out that there is a property called "AutoGenerateColumns" that needed to be turned off. Well I feel like a heel. Thanks!

Comment: This is from memory but do you need to set AutoGenerateColumns=false on the DataGrid?

Comment: @ChrisO If you could change this to answer, I will give it to you. Thanks for letting me know about that property!

Comment: Glad it helped. I created an answer for you to accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property to false on your `DataGrid`. Then it will only use the columns you specified.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set its `AutoGenerateColumns` to `False`. By default it is `True`.

If you want to show all fields of your class. do not set any columns in XAML.

But if you want to show selective columns, then set `AutoGenerateColumns` to false and write individual columns in XAML.